# How do I use display:flex and justify-content:space-between, where the flex-item gets centered if there is only one of them?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` that is `display: flex` with an unknown number of flex items. I want to use `justify-content: space-between`, but the problem is that when there is *one* item, it goes to the left side, whereas I want it to go to the center. Is there a CSS only solution to this?

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class='flex-item'></div>
    ...n flex-items...
</div>
```

Then I put some block elements in there (class-name - `.flex-items`) and due to `justify-content: space-between`, it makes the space go between the `div`s evenly so that the left-most `div` touches the left border and the right-most `div` touches the right border. It's responsive. My problem is that the default behavior when there is only one `flex-item` is that it is left aligned but I want it to be center aligned. What is a purely CSS solution?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexItem:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Cool that's even better

Comment: @MaryMelody you wanna post an answer?

Comment: It's fine, all I have done is just replaced the `:only-child` selector from your answer. :)